# Setting Date text object with correct formatting string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I can not figure out the secret format string to get my time displayed into a time text box.  The time is stored in the database in this format '10:30 AM'  DeliveryTime is defined as a string in the database.  I have tried various versions similar to this below to no avail.  Please help.

```
<input type="time" id="DeliveryTime" name="DeliveryTime" class="form-control" value="@Model.DeliveryTime.ToString("hh:mm tt")">
```

Comment: Here is the error message I get:  CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Why are you calling `.ToString()` on a `string`? Normally you would use that format when you have a `DateTime` object.. example: `DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt")` - not with strings.

Comment: Also, Bootstrap has nothing to do with this question. You can remove that from the title and the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the format of the value in the database (10:30 AM) and the format you are trying to use: `hh:mm tt`, they are the same.. so all you need to do is display it directly:

```
<input type="time" id="DeliveryTime" name="DeliveryTime" class="form-control" value="@Model.DeliveryTime">
```

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I already tried just displaying it directly.  Maybe because it is a bootstrap 3 class it does not work.  I had the same problem with the date display until someone gave me the exact display format string to use and then it worked.  Here is the html from a view source, it shows the correct value there, but it does not appear in the input box in the browser.  <input type="time" id="PickupTime" name="PickupTime" class="form-control" value="10:30 AM">

Comment: I think I see most of the problem now.  The control is outputting in 24 hour time which is the format getting sotred in the database.  Then when you pull the data from the database and post it back in the format it was saved in: 17:00 it displays correctly as 5:00 PM

Comment: my seed method was adding time values like '10:30 PM' to the database which the bootstrap date text box can't handle, since it needs to be in 24 hour format without the 'AM / PM'.